# What is causing this link to error saying "is not a valid virtual path"?

Tags: javascript, iis

I have some code that works locally but when I put it up live, it causes an error. Not just an error, but the page doesn't load and I get a huge error page that states:

> '/Clients/CMCDFMIS/gateway.htm?p=Dallas' is not a valid virtual path.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException:
>   '/Clients/CMCDFMIS/gateway.htm?p=Dallas' is not a valid virtual path.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): '/Clients/CMCDFMIS/gateway.htm?p=Dallas'
>   is not a valid virtual path.]    System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String
>   virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions options) +8877083
>   System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String virtualPath) +9
>   System.Web.UI.PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(String virtualPath,
>   String inputFile, HttpContext context) +163
>   AtgHttpHandler.AtgHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +804
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +181    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4062;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5692

HTML:

```
<a href="../gateway.htm?p=Dallas">
```

What I am doing with it is in JavaScript:

```
urlExtract = location.search
    foundExtract = urlExtract.split("=")[1];
    if(foundExtract == "Dallas"){
        //do something
    }
    else if(foundExtract == "Legacy"){
        //do something
    }
```

I don't think it is really getting to the JavaScript though. I have used this `urlextract` code on another site years and years ago so I am not sure why in this case it is giving me problems?

Comment: It's not related to js. That is a server side error. Your server isn't configured to handle `'/Clients/CMCDFMIS/gateway.htm?p=Dallas'`.

Comment: What is the correct virtual path to `gateway.htm` ?

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you might be specifying a (relative) URL, where in fact a file system path is expected. (But with the code you have shown so far, nothing more specific can be said about your problem – apart from, as already mentioned, it has little to do with your JavaScript, as it is a server-side error from your .NET code.)

Comment: I know nothing about the server side of this web page and as far as I know, there is no server side code in effect. In a AngularJS controller in a .js file, the path "../gateway.htm?p=Dallas" is being specified in a variable that is placed in the html file like so: <a href = "{{navigation.link}}">. gateway.htm is one folder back from the html file that contains the a tag. The web page this is on is retrieved when a client logs in, but the page itself doesn't use any other language. Again, this is just as far as I know. I created the client side code.

Comment: @scrappedcola perhaps you could elaborate on that? ?word=anotherword Can be attached to the end of any URL and the page will still load without issue. Can type in google.com?hi=bye and it will still load.

Comment: http://www.url.com/Clients/CMCDFMIS/gateway.htm is an example of the url, right? Well as stated above, I can add anything I want to the end of http://www.google.com and it will still load. Without even adding it to my code, if I try to add something, anything, like ?hi=bye to the end of *my* url it shows that error page.

Comment: No actually it can't add whatever you want to a url and expect it to not error out. You do have a server, whether or not you are aware of it, as that is the nature of the web. It's a server-client architecture. Where do you get `'/Clients/CMCDFMIS/gateway.htm` from? Who gave you that url or what tutorial are you following? It looks like you are running ASP.NET. Do a search for '[HttpException (0x80004005): is not a valid virtual path' and it might aid in your debugging.

Comment: @scrappedcola Yes I am aware of the presence of the server. It is on a server. What I am saying though is that the specific page(s) that I created for *after* the login part to the website does not use any language beyond HTML and JS. I am not sure what you mean by "No actually it can't add whatever you want to a url and expect it to not error out." What I mean is you *can* type in google.com?p=Dallas and google.com *will still load*. /Clients/CMCDFMIS/gateway.htm is the page that loads after login. /Clients/CMCDFMIS/FOLDER/anotherpage.htm is where *../gateway.html?p=Dallas* link is located.

Comment: www.myurl.com/Clients/CMCDFMIS/gateway.htm is the page that loads after login I should say. So /Clients/CMCDFMIS/gateway.htm is a location path.

Comment: `Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4062; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5692` tells you the error is coming from ASP.NET on the server. .NET can handle url routing through a routing table or the web.config. Figure that part out and you wont' have the issue. There isn't a way for this to be directly caused by JS.

Comment: @scrappedcola I know it's not directly caused by the JS. It's just text being attached to the URL and like I said, it can be attached to any URL. I just don't understand why not this one. And if I am going to talk to the server side guys I needed a little more information about the problem, considering I've never seen this give such a fuss.

Comment: It's pretty simple. Just tell them you are getting this error `'/Clients/CMCDFMIS/gateway.htm?p=Dallas' is not a valid virtual path.` when you attempt that path. They will fix it for you, if you want to understand the issue do a search for `ASP.NET not a valid virtual path`. There is nothing on your side to understand other than the server isn't configured for the path you are attempting.